# How to remove duplicate tuples using scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I want to remove the duplicate tuples. for example, these are the tuple values

```
(eraser,pen)
(pen,eraser)
(pen,book)
(pen,pencil)
(book,pen)
(book,pencil)
(pencil,pen)
(pencil,book)
```

I want the result as,

```
(eraser,pen)
(pen,book)
(pen,pencil)
(book,pencil)
```

Note: These tuples are in the form of (String,String)

Comment: Try to put the all the elements in a scala set - the duplicates will be auto removed - http://w3z.in/632

Comment: sir, Actually I got these tuples after calculating some operations. BUt here (eraser,pen) & (pen,eraser) occurs, these two are same. so I need only one.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can edit the question and explain the problem in more detail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List(
  ("eraser","pen"),
  ("pen","eraser"),
  ("pen","book"),
  ("pen","pencil"),
  ("book","pen"),
  ("book","pencil"),
  ("pencil","pen"),
  ("pencil","book")
).map{case (a, b) => if(a > b) (a, b) else (b, a)}.distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

```
//val l = List(...)
(l foldLeft List.empty[(String,String)]){
  case (l,a) if !l.contains(a) && !l.contains(a.swap) => a :: l
  case (l, _) => l
}
```